# Codeigniter 2.0/Facebook Connect - class init problem

Tags: codeigniter, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'll go ahead and feel silly in front of everyone, cuz I can't spot what the issue here is, though I suspect it will be a real groaner. maybe describing it will jog something in my mind.

i am doing a Facebook Connect integration with CI2.0, based on this guy's work:

http://hitsend.ca/2010/10/facebook-connect-user-authentication-using-the-new-graph-api-in-codeigniter/

which I've upgraded to 2.0

some relevant code bits are:

config/facebook.php:

```
 $config['facebook_api_key'] = 'xxx';  (it is the ID, not the key, as he misnamed his array key)
 $config['facebook_secret_key'] = 'xxx';
```

controllers/fb_login.php

```
    function index() {
        $this->load->library('fb_connect');
```

libraries/fb_connect.php

```
    include(APPPATH.'libraries/facebook/facebook.php');

    class fb_connect {
          ....

        function fb_connect()
        {
            //Using the CodeIgniter object, rather than creating a copy of it
            $this->_obj =& get_instance();

            //loading the config paramters for facebook (where we stored our Facebook API and SECRET keys
            $this->_obj->load->config('facebook');
            //make sure the session library is initiated. may have already done this in another method.
            $this->_obj->load->library('session'); 

            $this->_api_key        = $this->_obj->config->item('facebook_api_key');
            $this->_secret_key    = $this->_obj->config->item('facebook_secret_key');

            $this->appkey = $this->_api_key;

            //connect to facebook
            $this->fb = new Facebook(array(
                          'appId'  => $this->_api_key,
                          'secret' => $this->_secret_key,
                          'cookie' => true
                        ));
```

and finally, the facebook php library:
libraries/facebook/facebook.php

```
  public function __construct($fb_config) {
print_r($fb_config);
    $this->setAppId($fb_config['appId']);
    $this->setApiSecret($fb_config['secret']);
    if (isset($fb_config['cookie'])) {
      $this->setCookieSupport($fb_config['cookie']);
    }
```

The best way I can describe the issue is just to give you the output of print_r($fb_config):

```
Array ( [facebook_api_key] => xxx [facebook_secret_key] => xxx)
```

and 
Message: Undefined index: appId
Message: Undefined index: secret

The facebook __construct() has been loading with the config file's $config[] array; no idea why it is doing this.

Thanks in advance for any leads or spottings of "dumb things I've done"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, the array returning the wrong keys was what i was trying to work out. turns out, an earlier attempt to set up Facebook Connect was still on the dev server, and was auto-loading a library called "facebook" which was not the same as the current one we are using. this autoloading was calling the new library too early. not clear why it was using the config file's array, but think I would have to dig through the core classes to work that out, and not so interested

Answer (score 0):

The array returns two keys: `facebook_api_key` and `facebook_secret_key`, while the constructor is trying to read keys `appId` and `secret`

Also, the library you're using might be out of date. [The current source](http://hitsend.ca/2010/10/facebook-connect-user-authentication-using-the-new-graph-api-in-codeigniter/) (`libraries/facebook/facebook.php`), lines 186-88 read:

```
public function __construct($config) {
    $this->setAppId($config['appId']);
    $this->setApiSecret($config['secret']);
```

Comment: yes, the array returning the wrong keys was what i was trying to work out.

turns out, an earlier attempt to set up Facebook Connect was still on the dev server, and was auto-loading a library called "facebook" which was not the same as the current one we are using. this autoloading was calling the new library too early. not clear why it was using the config file's array, but think I would have to dig through the core classes to work that out, and not so interested